# is there any relation between naming the file and express reading it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am writing a simple todo app and this is a piece of the code

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));


app.get('/' , (req, res)=>{
   res.sendFile("index.html")
})
app.use('/api/todos' , todoRoutes);


app.listen(3000 , ()=>{
  console.log(" Server runing on port 3000");
})
```

---

first it didn't work because i was sending file with name of app.html
even the name was right in the real file and in the code but it didn't work until i review the source code of the instractour and i rename the file name to index.html inside the code and the real file in the directory and it works , then i changed it again to another name but it breakes again so is there any relation ??

Comment: no there is no connection between file names. File names could be anything, the path you're using must be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the file sent through `res.send` must match the name of your html file you wish to send.

Comment: i know that but i was using the same name of the file i wanted to send but it didn't work until the exact name of (index.html) if i used another name like (app.html)  for the file and the code it didn't work which is annoying so i put this q